# Spring Testing with JUnit4 Runner does not work after trying different solutions

Tags: java, junit4, spring-test

When autowiring my spring test class with the JUnit4 Test Runner the context startup yields the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.mypackage.TestClass': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.mypackage.ServiceClass com.mypackage.TestClass.service; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.mypackage.ServiceClass] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

### My Setup

The `TestClass` is annotated as followed

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/testContext.xml"})
```

The autowired fields are annotated like this

```
 @Autowired
 ACrudRepository repository; // is autowired

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("service")
 ServiceClass service; // is NOT autowired
```

The `testContext.xml` has the following Bean definition (and some more):

```
<bean class="com.mypackage.ServiceClass" id="service">
    <property name="someBoolean" value="false"/>
    <property name="otherBoolean" value="false"/>
    <property name="someList">
      <list><value>withOneValue</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mypackage"/>
```

**What I have tried:**

- `@Qualifier("service")`
- Checked [What is a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173982/what-is-a-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)
- Checked [NoSuchBeanDefinitionException using @Autowired in spring test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703286/nosuchbeandefinitionexception-using-autowired-in-spring-test)
- added `<component-scan>` in xml with `@Service/@Component` on `ServiceClass`
- added `@ComponentScan` on `TestClass`

Comment: try adding `autowire="byName"` in` <bean class="com.mypackage.ServiceClass" id="service">`.along with @Qualifier("service") on your autowired bean

Comment: Does not work unfortunately

Comment: where is your testContext.xml file?

Comment: @NawnitSen it is placed within the `test/resources/spring/testContext.xml` directory. As mentioned in the question the `<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mypackage"/>` is found and it's beans are injected. Therefore the `testContext.xml` should be fine

Comment: can you try doing it using java configuration once rather than using xml file? or maybe this could help "https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5/issues/6"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this projekt (which was not mentioned here) was the `<tx:annotation-driven/>` tag and `@Transactional` annotation in the autowired bean. This annotation usualy uses java interface-based-proxy which can not be autowired, because they are not of the same type of the class.

To Fix this we used the tag `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>`.

Much thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19624412